# How to manage tempvars related to usernames in a multi-user split access database

Tags: database, ms-access

thanks in advance for any help.

I am building an access database with the following charactersitics:

1. It is expected to be used simultaneously by several users (my plan is to split it when it is finished).
2. When users open the database, a login form asks for username/password and the username info is stored in a tempvar using a macro in the form.
3. A Public function in a separate module gets the tempvar information. This public function is used to input the username to a field when users change records in tables. This is done with a data macro.

Everything works fine so far, my question is (sorry if it is silly, it is the first time I split a database for multi-user)... what will happen after I split the database and distribute the front end to my users? I assume that each user must have a separate copy of the front end so that the username tempvar does not get mixed up when more than one user logs in? Each front end will manage its tempvar locally (macros are moved to the frontend when a db is split, correct)?

Thanks!

Comment: Once you get "most" of the tables done (and you not changing + adding tables every day?). Then you find that table structurers and changes calm down to a dull roar. At that point you VERY much want to split. Do not develop the whole system un-split. Splitting can introduce some issues - and you want to have seen/felt/used the database as split during this development process. Of course table changes are "harder" when split. You exit front end, go to back end, change the tables or add a new table. Now back to FE, and then you have to re-link the database. So, split asap.

Answer (score 1):

Correct.

TempVars are stored in VBA, in memory, so aren't present in the database at all. Each user has its own set of TempVars, so these won't conflict. And they're not database-specific when working with linked/referenced databases, macros (including data macros) will have access to all of them. They are application-specific, so if you open up a second instance of Access, it comes with its own set of TempVars.

Keep in mind that if you don't compile your database, users are free to inspect and change TempVars at will, which can be a problem for security. If you want to keep well-intentioned users from accidentally doing something they shouldn't, it's fine, if you want to repel attackers I've yet to see an implementation using TempVars that I couldn't trick in an hour.